# How to setup for BND project starting with enRoute to run on ApacheFelix and OSGI 6?

Tags: osgi, bnd, enroute

I have tried to follow on the tutorials from enRoute and then **customize them for OSGI 6.**

I have a top project that is a generated as enRoute project and it has the enRoute dependencies and bnd maven plugins. 
I have **added extra dependencies** : osgi.core:6.0.0, org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,shell,console

Also, there is a Maven module created as enRoute Application and that uses the top project as parent and imports the extra dependencies from there.

After running **mvn package** on the module, I get some errors:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-export-maven-plugin:4.1.0:export (default) on
>   project my-bundle: null: MojoExecutionException:

Before this NullPointer, I see that bnd/maven **is trying to collect dependencies** and it does find my stuff : example.my-project.my-module, osgi.core, org.apache.felix.framework, org.apache.felix.gogo.shell, etc.

> [DEBUG] my-module: adding resource javax.servlet-api version=3.1.0
>   version=9.4.15.v20190215 [DEBUG] my-module: adding resource
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload version=1.3.3 [DEBUG] my-module: adding
>   resource org.apache.commons.io version=2.6.0 [DEBUG] my-module: adding
>   resource org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api version=1.1.2 [DEBUG]
>   my-module: adding resource org.apache.felix.framework version=6.0.2
>   [DEBUG] my-module: adding resource example.my-project.my-module
>   version=1.0.0.201905020747 [DEBUG] my-module: list(null)
>   [org.apache.felix.http.jetty,
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.shell, org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api, jaxb-api,
>   osgi.core, org.apache.felix.framework,
>   javax.servlet-api,
>   example.my-project.my-module, 
>   org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard,
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.command, 
>   org.apache.felix.configadmin, org.osgi.service.log,
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime, 
>    org.apache.felix.webconsole]

Then Maven is trying to update the runbundles with an error :

> [DEBUG] init [DEBUG] Line is empty,
>   args=C:/workspace/my-project/my-module/target/tmp/export/my-module/cnf/cache/4.1.0/bnd-cache
>   [DEBUG] Original -runbundles was:      \
>     org.apache.felix.gogo.shell;version=1.0.0,\
>     org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime;version=1.0.10,\
>     org.apache.felix.gogo.command;version=1.0.2,\
>     org.apache.felix.webconsole;version=4.3.4,\
>     org.apache.felix.http.jetty;version=4.0.6,\
>     org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api;version=1.1.2 [DEBUG] Resolved
>   -runbundles is:    null

Original -runbundles was filled by me by hand as I was trying to help bnd. But BND did not update with new ones (in fact, it did not update at all)

1. Is this the correct way to include new bundles in your project? To add the them as dependencies (and later, the maven plugins from bnd will update my .bndrun files with entries in -runbundles)?
2. What plugin updates the -runrequires in the .bndrun and where do I put my entries to get them read by BND?
3. Same question for -buildpath in .bndrun
4. Same question for -runfw in .bndrun

Comment: It would be better to report this as a bug against bnd: https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues. Be sure to specify the exact version of bnd and JDK you are using, along with as much detail as possible about your project.

Comment: @NeilBartlett ok, makes sense. rephrased the question to be more about how to do things with BND. the bug report on BND : https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues/3172